# Laravel - Limit each child item efficiently

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this:

```
$commentReplies = Comment::whereIn('comment_parent_id', $CommentsIDs)
                                  ->take(2)->get();
```

Where `$CommentsIDs` is an array of 3 parent comment ids (1,2,3).

I am trying to retrieve 2 replies for each of the $commentsIDs if they exist.
So a total of 6 replies (2 for each comment) should come back with the query, if the replies exist, nothing more. However, with take(2) in there, it limits the replies to 2, and we only get 2 replies for one of the comments.
How can it be setup to get 2 replies for each of the comment IDs in the most efficient way, and how can they get rendered in the view with the correct nesting?

Something like:

```
Comment 1
--Comment 1 Reply 1 (load this)
--Comment 1 Reply 2 (load this)
--Comment 1 Reply 3 (don't load this)
--Comment 1 Reply 4 (don't load this)
Comment 2
--Comment 2 Reply 1 (load this)
--Comment 2 Reply 2 (load this)
--Comment 2 Reply 3 (don't load this)
Comment 3
(no replies, don't load anything)
```

**Update:**
Here is the Comment Model:

```
class Comment extends BaseModel {

 public function latestTwoComments()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('Comment','comment_parent_id')->latest()->nPerGroup('comment_parent_id', 2);
 }

}
```

Query:

```
$comments = Comment::with('latestTwoComments')->get();
dd(DB::getQueryLog());

// Result:
'query' => string 'select * from (select `comments`.*, @rank := IF(@group = comment_parent_id, @rank+1, 1) as rank_575b053fb57f8fab5bc86dd324b39b91, @group := comment_parent_id as group_575b053fb57f8fab5bc86dd324b39b91 from (SELECT @rank:=0, @group:=0) as vars, comments where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null order by `comment_parent_id` asc, `created_at` desc) as comments where `comments`.`deleted_at` is null and `rank_575b053fb57f8fab5bc86dd324b39b91` <= ? and `comments`.`comment_parent_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?'... (length=603)
```

Comment: So far so good. As you can see the query takes only 2 comments per each `comment_parent_id`, so what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, it load 2 replies per comment, but for some reason it also loads all the comments and replies as well. And the same replies that are nested as 2, are also being retrieved from the database as comments (unnested). I was only trying to get what I need and not more. So if I have 40 comments, this query puts in 40 ids in the comment_parent_id (? ? and 38 more ?) area, so loads everything it seems still, in addition to the correct nesting. Just trying to get the parent comment, 2 nested replies for each, and that's it.

Comment: That's different story my friend. If you need only parent comments, then (assuming `comment_parent_id` is nullable) do this: `Comment::whereNull('comment_parent_ud')->with('latestTwoComments')->get()` - it will load only parents and 2 children for each of them.

Comment: `reverse` after `get` works on the parent comments collection, so it doens't make sense. Latest comments are ordered by `created_at` desc, I don't know why 3 should be before 4 or whatever. You must work it out, you already have the code, the query that is executed, so it's all there.

Comment: Okay - I'll keep trying. Thank you for all your help and great articles on your site!

Comment: I created a package for this: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `limit`/`skip` when eager loading, for it will limit whole related result.

I suppose you use **MySQL**, so here is what you need: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

It's way to long to paste here, so just to get the idea: You need MySQL variables to do the job of fetching n per parent for you, like:

```
public function latestTwoComments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Comment', 'comment_parent_id')->latest()->nPerGroup('comment_parent_id', 2);
}

//then
$comments = Comment::with('latestTwoComments')->get();
// now all the comments will have at most 2 related child-comments
```

Note: it's meant for `hasMany` relation and **MySQL**

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking a solution for this and you came up with one, +1 my friend :-)

Comment: Hmmm.. I tried having the latestTwoComments() relationship in the Comment model, which extends BaseModel, with all the mySql in BaseModel, but not working for me, the query can't find things. But when I follow your site example, and put the code latestTwoComments() and the hasMany in the Post model, it executes the query correctly. So it can't work in the comments model itself? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I noticed that it's actually searching in the posts_id IN(?, ?, etc..) when it's in the post model, so I can't seem to get it to work just right in the comments model itself.

Comment: You must have done something wrong. It works just the same for self-referencing table. Show your relation for child-comments.

Comment: I updated the question to show the model, did I do something wrong or miss something?

Comment: I suppose there's 2nd param missing in that relation: `hasMany('Comment', 'comment_parent_id')`, so obviously it won't work, since Eloquent will search for `comment_id` foreign key.

Comment: I updated the model, but the query now loads all, not limiting to latest two comments. I am also not sure how it will know to only get certain comments in the $CommentsIDs which is a list of latest 5 comments.

Comment: And how you execute the query? The way I showed works with eager loading, you tried to load the comments without using relation. Show whole code, otherwise I cannot help you.