# Push an array into Laravel collection with matching keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have a collection called `User`, I also have an array containing two models `Post` relating to the `User` model.

The `User` collection contains a primary key `id` and each model in my `Post` collection I have a foreign key `user_id`.

I am currently executing the following:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        if ($post->user_id == $user->id) {
            $user->posts->push($post);
        }
    }
}
```

This somewhat works, but not entirely because it pulls in all related posts instead of the recent two posts a user has made.

---

The array looks like the following:

[image]

My `User` schema looks like; with a hasMany relationship to `Post`:

[image]

Comment: Are you simply trying to associate N `$posts` with `$user`?

Comment: Why would you want to insert some of the manually? You should more than likely be using Laravel relationships and doing something like `$users = Users::with('Posts')->all()`

Comment: @ash, yes pretty much.

Comment: @Jeremy Harris, as I mentioned in my question, I only want two most recent posts of each user and I haven't been able to figure out how to do that in eloquent so had to run a manual query for that data.

Comment: @zen I hope my answer helps you solve your problem :)

Comment: The below solutions will only work if you are retrieving one user. For a collection, they won't work because it is not as simple as adding limit or take. It's more complex, and I suggest reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247467/laravel-limit-each-child-item-efficiently#answer-26251935

Comment: @ThomasKim Awesome! That did it! Thank you so much.  If you want to put that in the answer I will mark it and release bounty to it.

Comment: Thanks :) I posted it as an answer, although I feel weird doing that because it wasn't my answer. Lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use query constraints / eager loading to do this. Doing so will only work if you are retrieving the posts for one user. However, if you try to retrieve the posts for multiple users, it will fail because eager loading / query constraints will limit the related results as a whole. To understand, you have to look at the queries Eloquent generates. Lets take a look at an example where you only need one user's posts.

```
$user = User::with(['posts' => function($query) {
    $query->limit(2);
}])->find(1);
```

In this example, we are getting a user with a primary key of 1. We also also retrieving his/her posts but limiting it so we only retrieve 2 posts. This works, and it will generate 2 queries similar to this:

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1) limit 2
```

Okay. Now, why doesn't this work if you try to get more than 1 user (or a collection of users)? For example:

```
$user = User::with(['posts' => function($query) {
    $query->limit(2);
}])->get();
```

In this case, I changed `find(1)` to `get()`, and it will generate 2 queries like this:

```
select * from `users`
select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (?, ?, ?, ... ?) limit 2
```

It's important to take a look at the second query. It's retrieving all the related posts, but at the end, you'll see that it has `limit 2`. In other words, it's limiting the entire related collection to only 2, which is why query constraints do not work for this.

Achieving this is actually pretty complex, but a fellow member ([Jarek Tkaczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/jarek-tkaczyk)) came up with a solution using MySQL variables, which you can find here: [Laravel - Limit each child item efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247467/laravel-limit-each-child-item-efficiently#answer-26251935)

Answer (score 3):

You can load the posts associated to a `User` using `with`, something like

```
$user = User::with('posts')->find($id);
```

But your scenario sounds specifically collecting the latest two `Post` belonging to a `User`. To limit your results you can also use scopes.

Something like the following on your `Post` model would work:

```
public function scopeLatest($query, $latest = 2)
{
    return $query->limit($latest);
}
```

Then collect these by:

```
// The user record.
$user = User::find($id);

// Latest 2 posts for this user.
$posts = $user->posts()->latest();

// Latest 5 posts for this user.
$posts = $user->posts()->latest(5);
```

However, should you with to load the latest 2 posts with the user in a single query - then you could make a new relation:

```
public function latestPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class,  'post_id', 'id') 
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
        ->limit(2);
}
```

This would work in the following way:

```
// Load the user with the latest 2 posts.
$user = User::with('latestPosts')->find($userId);

// Access these using; this will be a Collection containing 2 `Post` records.
dd($user->latestPosts);
```

Basically with Eloquent, when you call `$this->latestPosts` Eloquent will run `latestPosts()` and hydrate the related records.  Using `with` this hydration occurs with a single query and the relations are already defined.

The difference between the method `latestPosts()` and the property `$latestPosts` is simple.

The method will always return a specific Relation Collection allowing you to chain additional conditions;

So: `$user->latestPosts()->get()` is the same as `$user->latestPosts`.

Comment: Nah that won't work.  Looks like `sync` method actually deletes stuff from the database which I do not want.  The second solution is a problem because that will fetch all `posts` not just 2 most recent for each user.  The third solution also will not work because that fetches all posts for the user rather than only last 2.

Comment: With `sync` as my example shows you can parse false in the second parameter to NOT delete things.

Comment: @zen I've updated my answer, this will help clear things up.

Comment: does `sync` work on this type of relationship? I'm reading about it in docs and I only see it mentioned for many-to-many associations.  I will check out the other parts of your answer and respond soon.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a reference to the source.

Comment: I do want to keep it in a single query.  So I'm trying to implement the last solution.  Now is that supposed to be for the User or Post model? Also how do any of these you posted determine the "last 2" rows of each group? Wouldn't it have to look at `created_at` timestamp or at least the `id` column?

Comment: @zen I have updated your question and my answer I'm sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: What is the `$userId` variable in the `find` clause?  Since I want last 2 posts from ALL users, am I supposed to put an array with all user's IDs there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a bit simpler with https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading constraints.

Example: Users have many Dogs, but only take 2

```
    $user = App\User::with(['dogs'  => function ($query) {
        $query->limit(2);
    }])->find($user_id);

    dump($user);
```

The anonymous constraining function would also have an orderBy in your case

Comment: What is the `$user_id` variable supposed to be? Since I want last 2 posts from ALL users, am I supposed to put an array with all user's IDs there?

Comment: @zen if you omit `find`, it'll get all users but you will need `->all()`

Comment: Yea so this doesn't really answer the question since it still needs to run once per each user.  I need a combination of `all()` and `limit(2)` per each so it can grab all data in one query.  The only reason I did an additional manual query was to fetch all the data for all users I need in one run.

Comment: obviously, I didn't write the exact code for you. I assumed you could figure out the differences you need to make for your own work

Comment: No I am saying your code will not work.  It has to run each time for each individual user, so if I had 500 users, it would run 500 times.  I could have done that already. My question was to get all users in one query.